# Xamarin Android - Obtener fecha de GPS

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, gps

tengo una consulta que hacerles. Tengo una app que funciona como reloj de asistencia laboral, y al momento de realizar la entrada o salida, obtengo los datos de GPS, estos son:

- Latitud
- Longitud
- Fecha y hora.

El detalle que tengo es que si se cambia la hora del dispositivo obtengo esa hora y no la hora real. La pregunta es, ¿cómo se obtendría la fecha correcta del GPS?

Hasta ahora tengo esto:

```
public void OnLocationChanged(GPS.Location location)
    {

        if (location != null)
        {
            longitudval = location.Longitude;
            latitudval = location.Latitude;
            date= Helpers.HelpMethods.GetLocalDateTime(location.Time);
            i++;
            if (i == 2)
            {
                decimal longitude = decimal.Parse(longitudval.ToString());
                decimal latitude = decimal.Parse(latitudval.ToString());
                catStores = db.GetStores(longitude, latitude);
            }
        }
    }
```

Mi método para obtener la fecha es este:

```
public static DateTime GetLocalDateTime(long fromGPSMiliseconds)
    {
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
        var startdate = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(fromGPSMiliseconds);
        dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(startdate.ToLocalTime().ToString());
        return dateTime;
    }
```

Muchas gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: 2 cosas: primero te recomiendo ir por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas cómo funciona el sitio y de paso obtienes tu primera medalla, en segundo lugar podrías hacer un servicio REST donde devuelva la fecha/hora del servidor y ese dato se utilice para marcar la asistencia en vez de usar la hora (manipulable) del teléfono. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilza el [Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro?hl=es-419) (de Google Maps) para obtener la hora actual de una coordenada geográfica (conocida su latitud y longitud). Al consultar el servicio, vas a obtener un JSON, del cual te interesan 2 propiedades: `dstOffset` y `rawOffset`. Ambos los puedes ocupar para calcular la hora de esa ubicación con una fórmula matemática.

Como referencia, utiliza [este link](http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.cz/2015/01/using-google-time-zone-api-to-convert.html), pero si quieres algo de código, sería algo así:

```
 var latitud = 49.22645;
 var longitud = 17.67065;
 var timestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;

 var timeRequestUrl = $"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location={latitud},{longitud}&timestamp={timestamp}&key={apiKey}";
 var timeJsonResponse = await HttpClient.GetStringAsync(timeRequestUrl);
 var timeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TimeRootObject>(timeJsonResponse);

 var newTimestamp = timestamp + timeObject.dstOffset + timeObject.rawOffset;
 var localDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(newTimestamp);
```

NOTA 1: `apiKey` es la llave del servicio que obtienes al registrarte y por supuesto, `localDate` es la hora en la ubicación de las coordenadas.

NOTA 2: `TimeRootObject` es la clase que modela el JSON obtenido

```
public class TimeRootObject
{
    public int dstOffset { get; set; }
    public int rawOffset { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string timeZoneId { get; set; }
    public string timeZoneName { get; set; }
}
```

Revísalo y me comentas.

Comment: hey Luis! gusto de verte por estos lares, bienvenido a bordo hermano :D

Comment: ¡Hola @fredyfx! Muchas gracias por la bienvenida, te había prometido echarme una vuelta por acá, así que aquí andamos con mucho gusto apoyando, ¡saludos! :D

Comment: ahora que se preparen las preguntas de Xamarin que elevas el cosmos y les das con todo el power 2.0!!! :D

Comment: ¡Que se armen las preguntas! ¡A darle con todo!

Comment: esoooooo!!!! :D

Comment: Yo quiero hacer lo mismo pero con Java para Android. Esa solución del API es buena, pero que pasa si no hay Internet en ese momento?